# R: find the correlation between two images - one picture and one heatmap

Tags: r, image-processing, heatmap, correlation

There are two images that need to be compared their correlation. One image was taken by a camera (Fig. 1); other image was a heatmap (Fig. 2) produced in R. They were cropped in the same size. Please see attached images.

I would like to know their changes of grey scale within that domain to answer this questions: do they have similar hot spots (i.e., brightness and darkness) within that domain?

Should I normalize these images in the grey scale? Should I convert Fig. 1 to the same heatmap format in Fig. 2 for comparison? Any useful tools in R to compare their gradients? Any suggestions or solutions for this task in R?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "correlation/similarity/difference"?  This sounds far too ambiguous to me.  For instance, both are squares of similar size but I don't think you have this similarity in mind...

Comment: Sorry for not specifying more details. I would like to know the color gradients within that dimension. The comparisons cannot be done in the gray scale, which compares their gradient of brightness/darkness. I put more explanation to my content. Thanks.